# Python Selenium switching 2 iframe with identical by ID, different src

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I'm trying to switch to another iframe with ID: "ifrBetslipHolder"
there are two iframe with the exact same ID with different src

When I switch to the iframe, I always got switched to the first one

if I do find_elements_by_id("ifBetslipHolder"), it returns only one item

```html
</span><span class="cIframeHolder" style="width: 355px; height: 433px;"><iframe scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="" class="cIframe" id="ifrBetslipHolder" name="ifrBetslipHolder" src="/fe/manager/blank.htm?bust=0.46149823458289685" style="width: 357px; height: 433px;" frameborder="no"></iframe><div class="winDragSurface" id="drag_winMan_19"></div></span></span><span class="winFrame" id="winMan_20" style="left: 550px; top: 150px; width: 369px; height: 472px; z-index: 57; display: block; visibility: visible;" closemode="1"><div class="winTrans" id="winBack_winMan_20" style=""></div><span class="winHeadbar" style="height: 30px;" id="winHead_0_winMan_20"><span class="winTitles"><span><span class="winTitleActive" panelid="winMan_20" id="winTitle_0_winMan_20">Ticket</span></span>
        </span><span class="winControl" id="winControl_winMan_20"><span class="winConCls" id="winCls_winMan_20" winid="winMan_20" headerbtnid="undefined"></span><span></span></span>
        </span><span class="cIframeHolder" style="width: 355px; height: 433px;"><iframe scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="" class="cIframe" id="ifrBetslipHolder" name="ifrBetslipHolder" src="/fe/manager/blank.htm?bust=0.4631218513461094" style="width: 357px; height: 433px;" frameborder="no"></iframe><div class="winDragSurface" id="drag_winMan_20"></div></span></span>
```

Hope to be able to switch to the second iframe w/ id "ifrBetslipHolder"

Comment: @anonymous Update the question with a bit more of the surrounding outerHTML for the both the `<iframe>` tags

Comment: try using the index.  You can switch to frame in Selenium by index.  These will be 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below logic.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//iframe[@id='ifrBetslipHolder'])[2]"))
```

Comment: just tried it, it gave TypeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object does not support indexing

Comment: Can please you try this `driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='ifrBetslipHolder']")[1])`.

Comment: already tried it before for any indexing... but it doesn't work since there is only one object.. :(

Comment: The inner find_elements should return 2 and out switch will perform on index 1. Can you print the number of frames before switch.to line `print(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='ifrBetslipHolder']"))` to see how many iframes are identified with that id.

Answer (score 0):

An ID in an HTML page should always be unique. However, many browsers and drivers support selecting duplicated IDs. You can use a different method such as `find_element_by_css_selector('#ifrBetslipHolder')[1]`.

Comment: just tried it without [1],  find_element_by_css_selector('#ifrBetslipHolder')
it returned <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="670c0702-1c06-40a9-a27e-136b37f1209c", element="8b554433-d5ce-44eb-b6eb-c22b62385a6f")>   (which doesn't support indexing)